# calling more than one ticker when using an Quantmod function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, quantmod

I have the below function which calls an options chain from yahoo finance, things work well when I am downloading one ticker, however, it does not work when I have more than one ticker, may I know if I am required to add a loop element in the function or I just simply make some errors writing this function? Many thanks.

```
library(quantmod)
library(pedquant)


option_chain<-function(ticker,exp){
  view_window <- function(dfr, var, x, pm){
    
    idx <- which(abs(dfr[, var]-x) == min(abs(dfr[, var] - x)))
    
    return(dfr[(idx - pm) : (idx + pm), ])
    
  }
  options<-getOptionChain(ticker,exp)
  call_filter<-options$calls[,c("Strike","Last","Vol")]

  put_filter<-options$puts[,c("Strike","Last","Vol")]

  ticker_price<-md_stock(ticker,type="real")
  price<-ticker_price$close
  call<-view_window(dfr=call_filter,
                    var="Strike",
                    x=price,
                    pm=7)
  
  put<-view_window(dfr=put_filter,
                   var="Strike",
                   x=price,
                   pm=7)
  
  colnames(call)<-c('Option Strike',"Call Price","Call Volume")
  colnames(put)<-c('Option Strike',"Put Price","Put Volume")
  
  
  print(ticker_price$symbol)
  print(ticker_price$time)
  print(price)
  print(call)
  print(put)
}
```

Test case with one ticker:

```
> ticker<-"AAPL"
> exp="2023-06-30"
> option_chain(ticker,exp)
[1] "AAPL"
[1] "2023-06-27 10:05:20 CST"
[1] 186.69
   Option Strike Call Price Call Volume
22         170.0      17.14          30
23         172.5      14.38           3
24         175.0      12.10          77
25         177.5       9.42          21
26         180.0       7.10         251
27         182.5       4.85        1252
28         185.0       2.74        3729
29         187.5       1.19       14873
30         190.0       0.38       12760
31         192.5       0.08        5576
32         195.0       0.03        2623
33         197.5       0.01         227
34         200.0       0.01          72
35         202.5       0.01           1
36         205.0       0.01          56
   Option Strike Put Price Put Volume
23         170.0      0.02         80
24         172.5      0.02        315
25         175.0      0.04         73
26         177.5      0.05        412
27         180.0      0.11       2857
28         182.5      0.27       3408
29         185.0      0.71       6642
30         187.5      1.68       3399
31         190.0      3.30        100
32         192.5      5.60          4
33         195.0      8.05        133
34         197.5     10.64          8
35         200.0     13.34         20
36         202.5     17.10         20
37         205.0     17.80          7
```

Test case with more than 1 ticker:

```
> ticker<-c("AAPL","BABA")
> exp="2023-06-30"
> option_chain(ticker,exp)
[1] "AAPL" "BABA"
[1] "2023-06-27 10:06:00 CST" "2023-06-27 10:05:58 CST"
[1] 186.69  86.92
   Option Strike Call Price Call Volume
22         170.0      17.14          30
23         172.5      14.38           3
24         175.0      12.10          77
25         177.5       9.55          24
26         180.0       7.10         251
27         182.5       4.85        1252
28         185.0       2.70        3759
29         187.5       1.19       15115
30         190.0       0.36       12894
31         192.5       0.08        5576
32         195.0       0.02        2637
33         197.5       0.01         227
34         200.0       0.01          72
35         202.5       0.01           1
36         205.0       0.01          56
   Option Strike Put Price Put Volume
22         167.5      0.03          2
23         170.0      0.02         80
24         172.5      0.02        315
25         175.0      0.04         89
26         177.5      0.05        412
27         180.0      0.11       2857
28         182.5      0.28       3460
29         185.0      0.73       8300
30         187.5      1.72       3613
31         190.0      3.32        106
32         192.5      5.60          4
33         195.0      8.05        133
34         197.5     10.64          8
35         200.0     13.34         20
36         202.5     17.10         20
```

As shown, the second case fails to display the options chain data for "BABA" (Alibaba).

All ideas are appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're using `print()` to return lots of results.  Only the last printed result gets saved in the object.  I would suggest, instead, returning a list that has the relevant pieces.  In the code below, I made a list that had the `call` and `put` frames returned and the symbol, time and price are saved as attributes to the list.  I also wrote a print function that would print the relevant information.  After that, you can use `lapply(ticker, function(x)option_chain(x, exp))` to return data for all required tickers - each one ends up as a different element in the list.

First, here's the modified `option_chain()` function:

```r
library(quantmod)
library(pedquant)


option_chain<-function(ticker,exp){
  view_window <- function(dfr, var, x, pm){
    
    idx <- which(abs(dfr[, var]-x) == min(abs(dfr[, var] - x)))
    
    return(dfr[(idx - pm) : (idx + pm), ])
    
  }
  options<-getOptionChain(ticker,exp)
  call_filter<-options$calls[,c("Strike","Last","Vol")]
  
  put_filter<-options$puts[,c("Strike","Last","Vol")]
  
  ticker_price<-md_stock(ticker,type="real")
  price<-ticker_price$close
  call<-view_window(dfr=call_filter,
                    var="Strike",
                    x=price,
                    pm=7)
  
  put<-view_window(dfr=put_filter,
                   var="Strike",
                   x=price,
                   pm=7)
  
  colnames(call)<-c('Option Strike',"Call Price","Call Volume")
  colnames(put)<-c('Option Strike',"Put Price","Put Volume")
  
  res <- list(cl=call, put=put)
  attr(res, "symbol") <- ticker_price$symbol
  attr(res, "time") <- ticker_price$time
  attr(res, "price") <- price
  class(res) <- "option_chain"
  res
}
```

Next is the `print()` method for the result

```r
print.option_chain <- function(x, ...){
  cat("Symbol: ", attr(x, "symbol"), "\n", sep="")
  cat("Time: ", attr(x, "time"), "\n", sep="")
  cat("Price: ", attr(x, "price"), "\n", sep="")
  cat("Call:\n")
  print(x$cl)
  cat("\nPut\n")
  print(x$put)
}
```

Now, we can run the code and look at the results:

```r
ticker<-c("AAPL","BABA")
exp="2023-06-30"
out <- lapply(ticker, function(x)option_chain(x,exp))
out
#> [[1]]
#> Symbol: AAPL
#> Time: 1687832620
#> Price: 186.72
#> Call:
#>    Option Strike Call Price Call Volume
#> 22         170.0      17.02          38
#> 23         172.5      14.69           4
#> 24         175.0      12.15          89
#> 25         177.5       9.65          25
#> 26         180.0       6.80         353
#> 27         182.5       4.51        1771
#> 28         185.0       2.38        5424
#> 29         187.5       0.96       19728
#> 30         190.0       0.25       25574
#> 31         192.5       0.06        6128
#> 32         195.0       0.02        2812
#> 33         197.5       0.02         494
#> 34         200.0       0.01          78
#> 35         202.5       0.01           2
#> 36         205.0       0.01          56
#> 
#> Put
#>    Option Strike Put Price Put Volume
#> 23         170.0      0.01        119
#> 24         172.5      0.02       1097
#> 25         175.0      0.04        170
#> 26         177.5      0.06        654
#> 27         180.0      0.11       3385
#> 28         182.5      0.28       5215
#> 29         185.0      0.77      12525
#> 30         187.5      1.90       6321
#> 31         190.0      3.70        283
#> 32         192.5      5.55        204
#> 33         195.0      8.50        143
#> 34         197.5     10.64          8
#> 35         200.0     13.34         20
#> 36         202.5     17.10         20
#> 37         205.0     17.80          7
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> Symbol: BABA
#> Time: 1687832620
#> Price: 87.14
#> Call:
#>    Option Strike Call Price Call Volume
#> 17            80       7.25           5
#> 18            81       6.47           7
#> 19            82       5.35          13
#> 20            83       4.55           3
#> 21            84       3.63          20
#> 22            85       2.55         391
#> 23            86       1.88         339
#> 24            87       1.43        2087
#> 25            88       1.01        3044
#> 26            89       0.63        1383
#> 27            90       0.49        4992
#> 28            91       0.29         297
#> 29            92       0.21        1244
#> 30            93       0.15         617
#> 31            94       0.10         109
#> 
#> Put
#>    Option Strike Put Price Put Volume
#> 24            80      0.04        284
#> 25            81      0.06         39
#> 26            82      0.09        173
#> 27            83      0.18        338
#> 28            84      0.33       1118
#> 29            85      0.57        959
#> 30            86      0.93        864
#> 31            87      1.37        456
#> 32            88      1.83         57
#> 33            89      2.49         16
#> 34            90      3.21         16
#> 35            91      4.00          3
#> 36            92      4.90          1
#> 37            93      5.80          5
#> 38            94      7.88         59
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Good answer! One comment: `print` methods should invisibly return the input, so you should add `invisible(x)` as the last line of the function. It also would be easier to access the symbol, time, and price if they were elements of the list rather than attributes on it.